# Need help writing a query Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

write a query to show the staffid, charge code, specialty id, specialty name, date consulted, patient number, and due date will be calculated using date consulted + 21

```
SELECT
    staffid, 
    chrgcode,
    dateconsulted,
    patientno,
    (dateconsulted + 21) "Due Date"
FROM
    staff_speciality,
    staff,
    speciality,
    consultation;
```

> SELECT staffid, chrgcode, dateconsulted, patientno, (dateconsulted + 21) "Due >Date"
>      *
>      ERROR at line 1:
>      ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
>      Connected to:
>      Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
>      SQL> describe speciality
>      Name Null? Type
>
> ---
>
> SPECID NOT NULL CHAR(4)
>      SPECNAME VARCHAR2(25)
>      SPECNOTES VARCHAR2(100)
>      SQL> describe staffid
>      ERROR:
>      ORA-04043: object staffid does not exist
>      SQL> describe staff
>      Name Null? Type
>
> ---
>
> STAFFID NOT NULL CHAR(2)
>      FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20)
>      LASTNAME VARCHAR2(20)
>      ROLE VARCHAR2(15)
>      GENDER CHAR(1)
>      DATEJOINED DATE
>      DATELEFT DATE
>      SQL> describe staffspeciality 
>      ERROR:
>      ORA-04043: object staffspeciality does not exist
>      SQL> describe staff_speciality
>      Name Null? Type
>
> ---
>
> STAFFID NOT NULL CHAR(2)
>      SPECID NOT NULL CHAR(4)
>      DATEQUALIFIED NOT NULL DATE
>      VALIDTILLDATE DATE
>      DETAILS VARCHAR2(100)
>      SQL> describe consultation
>      Name Null? Type
>
> ---
>
> CHRGCODE NOT NULL CHAR(7) 
>      STAFFID NOT NULL CHAR(2)
>      DATECONSULTED NOT NULL DATE
>      STARTTIME NUMBER(4,2)
>      PATIENTNO CHAR(7)
>      SQL> SELECT staffid, chrgcode, dateconsulted, patientno, (dateconsulted + 21) "Due Date"
>      2 FROM staff_speciality, staff, speciality, consultation;
>      SELECT staffid, chrgcode, dateconsulted, patientno, (dateconsulted + 21) "Due Date"
>      *
>      ERROR at line 1:
>      ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  `ON`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: What do I use? could you show an example

Comment: and alias the columns with the related table's aliases, such as `SELECT s.staffid .... from staff_speciality ss join staff s on s.staffid = ss.staff_id ....`

Comment: Could you show an example I don't know how to do that. Or could you link a website that could help me with that please?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I don't understand that at all.... :( why are you adding s. to staffid? what is ss? Why are you making s.staffid = ss.staff_id?

Comment: Your join is called **Cartesian Join**.  This is **VERY** bad thing. Read about it and see what you've done

Comment: This is the code that i'm supposed to use but i don't understand how to use it for this question. https://imgur.com/a/LW1CQWN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct such a query with ANSI-92 syntax

```
SELECT s.staffid, chrgcode, dateconsulted, patientno, (dateconsulted + 21) "Due Date"
  FROM staff_speciality ss 
  JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = ss.staffid
  JOIN speciality sp ON sp.specid = ss.specid
  JOIN consultation c ON c.staffid = s.staffid
```

where especially important to alias the `staffid` column in the select list ( you can also alias every columns explicitly ), since three tables have that as common column, and if not specified, Oracle cannot know which table's column is chosen without an alias, and `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` is raised due to this mistake.

Comment: SQL> SELECT s.staffid, chrgcode, dateconsulted, patientno, (dateconsulted + 21) "Due Date"
  2    FROM staff_speciality ss,
  3    JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = ss.staffid
  4    JOIN speciality sp ON sp.specid = ss.specid
  5    JOIN consultation c ON c.staffid = s.staffid
  6  ;
  JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = ss.staffid
             *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @Reece excuse me I realized that I forgot a comma after `staff_speciality ss`

Comment: SQL> SELECT s.staffid, chrgcode, dateconsulted, patientno, (dateconsulted + 21) "Due Date"
  2  FROM staff_speciality ss,
  3  JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = ss.staffid
  4  JOIN speciality sp ON sp.specid = ss.specid
  5  JOIN consultation c ON c.staffid = s.staffid;
JOIN staff s ON s.staffid = ss.staffid
           *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: @Reece you still send the same text, I already removed the comma.

Comment: Sorry I miss understood, that. Its working now thank you very much!